# create binary search tree from sorted list in R

Tags: r, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am practicing recursion and tried to implement a BST from a linked list. 
I tried to translate the solution from here to R:
[Create Balanced Binary Search Tree from Sorted linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235013/create-balanced-binary-search-tree-from-sorted-linked-list)

Given a vector `vec` I want to find the BST, for example:

```
  0
  / \
 -3   9
 /   /
-10  5


vec <- c(-10,-3,0,5,9)
```

This is my attempt to solve this recursively, but it does not work:

```
tobt <- function(vec, start, end) {
  if (start > end) return(NA)
  mid <- start + (end - start) / 2
  left <- tobt(vec, start, mid-1)
  right <- tobt(vec, mid+1, end)
  return(c(left, right))
}

tobt(vec, 1, 5)
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use structure that allow build trees, for example `list`. Second problem is ignoring *parent* that filled a node of tree with number.

A possible variant of your function:

```
tobt <- function(vec, start, end) {
  if (start > end) return(NULL)
  mid <- start + (end - start) %/% 2
  left <- tobt(vec, start, mid-1)
  parent <- vec[mid]
  right <- tobt(vec, mid+1, end)
  return(list(left=left, node = parent, right=right))
}
```