# creating a balanced tree from a sorted list in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm wondering how to create a balanced tree given a sorted list in Ocaml. I've implemented this in O(n log n) time, but was curious how to get it done more efficiently, as I understand it can be done in O(n) time.

I've looked at this thread [Create Balanced Binary Search Tree from Sorted linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235013/create-balanced-binary-search-tree-from-sorted-linked-list), and considered the answers, but am not too sure what the exact method is. The code is also in a language that i'm unfamiliar with, and the structure seems to be different from Ocaml, so I find it difficult to follow.

Below is my implementation for O(n log n) time :-)

```
let rec length l =
  match l with
    [] -> 0
  | _ :: t -> 1 + length t;;

let rec take_element l n =
  match l with
    [] -> raise Not_found
  | h::t -> if n > 1 then take_element t (n-1)
            else h;;

let takemiddle l  = take_element l (length l/2 + 1);;

let rec take n l =
  if n = 0 then [] else
    match l with
      h::t -> h:: take (n-1) t;;

let takefront l = take (length l/2) l;;

let rec drop n l =
  if n = 0 then l else
    match l with
      h::t -> drop (n-1) t;;

let takeback l = drop (length l/2 + 1) l;;

let rec tree_of_list l =
  match l with
  [] -> Lf
| h::t -> Br((takemiddle l), tree_of_list (takefront l), tree_of_list (takeback l));;
```

Thanks again for the help!!

p.s. This isn't for homework, I was just wondering how to improve the time complexity of my solution!!!

Comment: Side-comment: you can use List.length -wich is tail-recursive instead of your own - instead of defining your own length function

Answer (score 0):

A translation of the algorithm from the linked thread is quite straightforward:

```
type 'a tree = Empty | Branch of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree

let tree_of_list list =
  let rec recur low high input =
    if low = high then Empty, input
    else
      let mid = low + (high - low) / 2 in
      let left, input = recur low mid input in
      match input with
      | [] -> Empty, []
      | x::xs ->
        let right, input = recur (mid + 1) high xs in
        Branch (x, left, right), input in
  fst (recur 0 (List.length list) list)
```

I've made some minor changes: mutation has been replaced by state-passing, and my intervals are half-closed (eg, start and one-past-end).

An interesting variant might be to pass the *size* of the desired tree in place of an interval:

```
let tree_of_list list =
  let rec recur size input =
    if size = 0 then Empty, input
    else
      let half_size = size / 2 in
      let left, input = recur half_size input in
      match input with
      | [] -> Empty, []
      | x::xs ->
        let extra = (lnot size) land 1 in
        let right, input = recur (half_size - extra) xs in
        Branch (x, left, right), input in
  fst (recur (List.length list) list)
```

Comment: thank you!! one question, what is the fst that you're calling in the last line of the first segment? i dont see it anywhere else

Comment: It's the one from `Pervasives`, which returns the first element of a pair.